# Issue to load or use "model.h5" file using KERAS.NET in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, keras

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5ohi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J58X8.png)

should the mdl be like that?

I've tested the same model.h5 file on python and it works just fine.
is there anything that I am missing?

EDIT:

it goes through each contours in the image ( for loop (j) )

and Question is an NDArray

Question(j).PyObject {[[[0.63137257]\n  [0.86666667]\n  [0.00784314]\n  ...\n  [0.        ]\n  [0.        ]\n  [0.        ]]\n\n [[0.        ]\n  [0.45490196]\n  [0.27450982]\n  ...\n  [0.        ]\n  [0.        ]\n  [0.        ]]\n\n [[0.        ]\n  [0.0627451 ]\n  [0.        ]\n  ...\n  [0.        ]\n  [0.        ]\n  [0.        ]]\n\n ...\n\n [[0.22352941]\n  [1.        ]\n  [0.98823529]\n  ...\n  [0.        ]\n  [0.        ]\n  [0.        ]]\n\n [[0.        ]\n  [0.63137257]\n  [0.02352941]\n  ...\n  [0.        ]\n  [0.        ]\n  [0.        ]]\n\n [[0.        ]\n  [0.21568628]\n  [0.        ]\n  ...\n  [0.        ]\n  [0.        ]\n  [0.        ]]]}

references used:

```
Imports Keras.Layers
Imports Keras.Models
Imports Keras.Utils
Imports Keras.Callbacks

Imports Numpy

Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

Imports OpenCvSharp
Imports Python.Runtime
```

code:

```
Public Class OCR
    Dim pathModel As String = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\Model\model.h5"

    Function readDim(filenameImg As String) As String
        ' get model
        Dim mdl = Sequential.LoadModel(pathModel)

        ' get image
        Dim image As Mat = Cv2.ImRead(filenameImg)

        ...

        ' Set inputs    
        Dim Question = np.zeros(New Integer() {contours.Length, px2, px2, 1})

        ' contours
        Dim cnt = 0
        For j = 0 To contours.Length - 1

            ...

            ' prediction
            Dim predictions = mdl.Predict(np.expand_dims(Question(j), 0).astype(np.float32), 1, 1, 1,)

        Next

    End Function

End Class
```

The Error Exception at  `Dim predictions = mdl.Predict(np.expand_dims(Question(j), 0).astype(np.float32), 1, 1, 1,)`

Python.Runtime.PythonException: 'AttributeError : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write''

```
['  File "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\utils\\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler\n    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None\n', '  File "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\utils\\io_utils.py", line 79, in print_msg\n    sys.stdout.write(message)\n']   at Python.Runtime.PyObject.Invoke(PyTuple args, PyDict kw)
   at Python.Runtime.PyObject.InvokeMethod(String name, PyTuple args, PyDict kw)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at Keras.Base.InvokeMethod(String method, Dictionary`2 args)
   at Keras.Models.BaseModel.Predict(NDarray x, Nullable`1 batch_size, Int32 verbose, Nullable`1 steps, Callback[] callbacks)
   at Ballooning___2._0._0._0.OCR.readDim(String filenameImg) in C:\Users\User\Desktop\new Forms\Ballooning - 2.0.0.0\OCR.vb:line 304
   at Ballooning___2._0._0._0.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\User\Desktop\new Forms\Ballooning - 2.0.0.0\Form1.vb:line 36
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```